# custom control creation - strange behavior

Tags: c++, mfc

I've derived a small custom control from CStatic, added it to my dialog during initialisation using

```
myControl->Create("", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(...), this, IDC_ID);
```

And everything was fine. Then I decided my control would look better with a sunken edge, so I've changed the window creation code to

```
LPCSTR p =  AfxRegisterWndClass(CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW, ::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW),
                                (HBRUSH) ::GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH), 
                                ::LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION));

myControl->CreateEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, p, L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(...), 
           this, IDC_ID, 0));
```

Now everything mostly works, but if I start my application with mouse pointer outside my dialog and then move it over my custom control while bypassing other dialog controls, mouse pointer looks garbled for a fraction of second.

After then everything is fine, but this momentary glitch kinda bothers me. What could be causing it?

Comment: I've seen this on and off before too, do you have Aero enabled?

Comment: @Konrad - nope. I've looked into it a bit further and the weird thing is the glitch only occurs when my dialog is created on top of a Visual Studio window, whether my application is started from the IDE or not. Never happens above, say Explorer.